# How to create NFS share on Synology NAS so that only a particlar linux pc has write access?

Tags: mount, docker, nas, nfs

**What I have:**

- Synology NAS (IP x.x.x.11)

  - Docker installed, and a `docker` user and group,
  - running many containers using the `docker` user,
  - all containers' storage inside `/volume1/docker/`,
  - NFS share for `/volume1/docker/` (see footnote 1 below);
- Linux PC (IP x.x.x.10)

  - Docker installed, no `docker` user and group yet,
  - mounted NFS share as `/media/docker` on the PC (see footnote 1 below),
  - this user only has **read** access,
  - `sudo` has **write** access, but I don't want to run everything as root!

**What I want:**

- Run the containers using the **PC's CPU,**
- Keep the containers' **storage on the NAS,**
- **only this PC** (or possibly only a particular user on the PC?)
  shall have network access to the NFS share.

**Questions:**

1. On the NAS, how do I **prevent READ access** to the share from anywhere except that PC?
2. On the NAS, how do I **grant WRITE access** to the share, but only to this PC? (And only to a particular user??)
3. Do I need to set up a `docker` user and group on the PC? I could just **use the existing (non-root) user**, `uid=1001`.
4. On the PC, how do I **configure `/etc/fstab`** to give write access to that non-root user on the PC?

---

**Footnote:**

1. On the NAS, `sudo cat /etc/exports` gives:

```
/volume1/docker 192.168.1.10(rw,async,no_wdelay,crossmnt,no_root_squash,insecure_locks,sec=sys,anonuid=1025,anongid=100)
```

2. On the PC, `cat /etc/fstab` gives:

```
192.168.1.11:/volume1/docker /media/docker nfs rw,vers=4 0 0
```

Comment: Have you try to export it twice, one with r/w for only IP, second with r/o for all.

Comment: What I understand from your questions 1 and 2 is that you want to grant read AND write access to only PC ?

Comment: @RomeoNinov, *r/o for all* is incorrect, it should be disallowed for all except the server's docker user.

Comment: @PierU, yes correct! It's vital that the server's docker user can write; it's optional but desirable that nobody else can even read.

Comment: @TorbenGundtofte-Bruun, I just give idea how to make the share r/w for someone/some IP and r/o for other.

Comment: @TorbenGundtofte-Bruun So questions 1 and 2 are already answered, aren't they? You are exporting only to the IP address of the PC, so no other can access at all...

Comment: @PierU, Q2 is still unresolved: the normal user on the server only has read access. Write access is not given despite the `rw` option.

Comment: @TorbenGundtofte-Bruun Ah ok... You indeed probably need to have a `docker` user  on the PC. Actually I think that what matters is to have a user with the same `uid` than the `docker` user on the NAS.

Answer (score 1):

`/etc/exports` on the server (NAS) export the desired path:

```
/volume1/foo  192.168.1.10(async,rw,all_squash,anonuid=1038,anongid=65544)
# 192.168.1.10 is the only allowed client IP
# connections will be made as if with local user 1038, local group 65544
```

Then enter `exportfs -r` to refresh (activate the new settings).

`/etc/fstab` on the client (PC):

```
192.168.1.11:/volume1/foo /media/bar nfsvers=3 0 0
# 192.168.1.11 is the server
# forcing NFS version 3 because Synology NAS does not support version 4!
```

Then enter `mount -a` to activate the new settings.

On the client, `touch /media/bar/foo.txt` should now work, and `ls -l` will show that the file is created with uid=1038 and gid=65544.

Comment: Unless I missed something, this does not answer this part of the question 2: *"how do I grant WRITE access to the share, but only to this PC? **And only to a particular user**"*. The `all_squash` option will de facto give the write access to all users.

Comment: Thank you, good point! I would be happy if you could improve the answer (or post another).

Comment: As I wrote in a previous comment, I can't see obvious solutions apart from creating on the PC a user with the same uid/gid (at least the same uid) than on the NAS.